# Why " grep * " not working?

Tags: linux, grep

On these days learning linux, I found something confued me：

```
$ cat abcd
line One
line Two
line Three
$ cat abcd | grep *
$ _                       //nothing greped
$ cat abcd | grep ""
line One
line Two
line Three
$ cat abcd | grep "*"
$ _                       //nothing greped
```

**the "_" is just the cursor, don't get mistake :)**

who would explain this? Thanks

Comment: What is `_`? On my machine, it yields, `_: command not found`.

Comment: Also, what precisely did you hope `cat abcd | grep *` would print?

Comment: it's the cursor, just not blink here :)

Answer (score 3):

The glob `*` is expanded by the shell to an alphabetic list of all (non-dot) the files in the current directory. The arguments to `grep` are a search expression and a list of files. So `grep *` ends up using the first file name as the search expression. You are looking for the first file's name (as a regular expression) in the other files.

Grep searches standard input only if you do not supply any explicit file names. See:

```
echo moo | grep . /etc/issue
Handmade Linux for OS/X v 0.001
```

Incidentally, `*` is not a valid regular expression. As you have discovered, an empty search expression matches all input lines. A regular expression which matches all non-empty input lines is `.`; in regex, the dot is a metacharacter which matches one character, any character except newline. The kleene star is a suffix operator which allows for zero or more repetitions of the previous regular expression, so you frequently see the regex `.*` for "anything at all", but in this context, it is redundant, as you are already matching nothing at all with the empty search string.

Finally, it is considered bad form to `cat` a single file. Instead of `cat file | grep ""` you save a process and perhaps some [scorn](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) by having `grep` read the file directly; `grep "" file`

Answer (score 1):

The `grep *` is going to do "globbing" expansion against the files in the current directory.

I can't predict exactly what will happen, but the `*` will certainly match the `abcd` filename.  So you might end up searching for "abcd" in the `abcd` file.  Or you might end up searching for the name of the (lexographically) first file in the other files.

If the current directory was empty, you would end up searching for `*`.  But that won't work either because the first command line argument is a regex, and "*" is not a valid regex.

To prevent the globbing, write this:

```
$ cat abcd | grep "*"
```

... but that doesn't make sense for the reason given above.

To search for a literal "*" character:

```
$ cat abcd | grep "\\*"
```

Comment: The best way to find out what would happen would be to try `echo *`

Comment: Yea ... but >>I<< can't do that.  That's why it is hard for me to predict what will happen :-)

Answer (score 1):

Before `grep` sees a command line argument, that argument is parsed by the shell. For the shell, `*` is a wildcard for "all non-dot files in the current directory". Since the shell handles the argument first, your line gets turned into this:

```
cat abcd | grep abcd otherfile zfile
```

(assuming that those three files reside in your current directory). This is what `grep` gets to see of its arguments, but it's not what you want.

Instead, you could put the pattern for `grep` in quotation marks, so that it is *not* processed by the shell:

```
cat abcd | grep "*"
```

That's better, but still not what you want: `grep` uses regular expressions, not shell-style wildcarding. The asterisk, for `grep`, means "0..n repetitions of the previous character" - a character you did not specify. Close, but no cigar.

If you want an "any" pattern, you are looking for "0..n repetitions of an *arbitrary* character". The latter is represented by the period (`'.'`) in regular expressions:

```
cat abcd | grep ".*"
```

*That* is what you were looking for.

**Edit:** The other case is more easily explained. With `grep ""` you are looking for an *empty* string, which is present as a substring in any string.

Comment: Except `cat` is useless and the regex is useless. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: @tripleee: I've seen this "award" tossed around with glee on sites like SO. I don't think it is appropriate. We're not talking about production code here; the `cat` in this example is a generic stand-in for "when I'm grepping some arbitrary standard input". An answer is easier to comprehend when it doesn't turn an abstract example into something else entirely just for the sake of showing off your leet skills of avoiding "unnecessary" uses of `cat` -- but sticks with the original code and shows the few twists that are actually related to the core of the question.

Comment: I see it as misguided; an answer which fails to explain tangents and caveats is just less valuable than an answer which also tries to ensure that the basic approach is sound. It's not as bad as the "try `chmod 0777 *`" answers you sometimes see, but there is a commonality in the "just fix the symptoms" approach.

Comment: @triplee: I don't discuss three vs. four space indenting, or eqyptian vs. ANSI brackets either when answering, unless it's topical. There is a fine line between being verbosely helpful and being condescending.

Comment: Great explanation! But there is still a question: Why&How `$ cat abcd | grep ""` works? I mean it's just an empty string, what make it(`""`) diff from `"*"` -- while `"*"` match nothing?

Comment: `*` is a syntax error, so the behavior is "undefined", i.e. you should not rely on this behavior as it could change with the next system upgrade. A lenient interpretation could be that it means zero or more repetition of nothing, but again, just plain nothing should do just as well, and this interpretation is not specified. In fact, you can expect some versions of `grep` to abort with an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Bash always parses * as a wildcard placeholders for file in the directory. In your command bash undertands it as

```
cat abcd | grep abcd file1 file2 ...
```

so it only shows empty output as it doesn't what you are searching for

Comment: Not always.  If the `*` is quoted, it won't.